# C++/CLI: are local managed variables allowed in unmanaged class methods?

Tags: c++-cli

I know gcroot is used for holding a refrence to a managed object in a native class, but what about using managed objects as **local** variables inside an unmanaged class function ?
The compiler does not seem to generate an error on this, but is it "proper" ? Does it hurt performence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as a local managed object.  All managed objects are stored on the heap, required to let the garbage collector do its job.  You could only have a *reference* as a local variable.  A pointer at runtime.

Using an managed object reference in an unmanaged function is possible if you compile that code with /clr or `#pragma managed` in effect.  Such code will be translated to IL and gets just-in-time compiled at runtime, just like normal managed code.  It won't otherwise have the characteristics of managed code, there is no verification and you'll suffer all the normal pointer bugs.  And yes, it can hurt performance because such code doesn't get the normal optimizer love.  The optimizer built in the jitter isn't as effective because it works under time constraints.

Compile native code without the /clr option or use `#pragma unmanaged` inside your code to switch the compiler on-the-fly.

Comment: The sentence: 'Using an managed object reference in an unmanaged function is possible if you make a mistake' is misleading... it is _not_ a mistake to use managed objects in an "unmanaged function" (not native!). This is the normal way to use gcroot objects in an "unmanaged class".

Comment: I've been answering C++/CLI questions for a very long time.  I've yet to encounter an OP that actually *intended* for his C++ code to be compiled to IL.

Comment: If you use C++/CLI then you normally want to have IL code... mostly only for specific parts... but the OP was talking about using `gcroot`.. this assumes that he understands what he is doing... and if you are using gcroot, then the **only** way to use the gcroot object is to use IL code in an unmanaged class/function! Or do you see an other usage of gcroot???

Comment: Hans, please go back and study the difference between reference and value types.  Adding that to the mistakes Jochen has already pointed out, this answer is 100% wrong.

Comment: A value type value is not a managed object.  Please stop posting idiotic comments to my answers.

Comment: @Hans: Can you provide a demo of a `value class` with `#pragma unmanaged` in effect?  No, of course you cannot.  It is a managed type, and its instances are managed objects.

Answer (score 0):

Managed objects, both values of managed value types (`value struct`, `value class`, `enum class`) and handles to managed reference types (`ref struct`, `ref class`) can be used inside code which is compiled to MSIL.

And code that is compiled to MSIL can be part of unmanaged objects (for example, a virtual member function of a standard C++ type can be compiled to MSIL, and the Visual C++ compiler "It Just Works" technology will make sure that the v-table is set up correctly).  This is extremely useful when forwarding events and callbacks produced by standard C++ code into the managed GUI world.  But it is also applicable if you have an algorithm implemented in managed code (perhaps C#) that you want to call from C++.

As Hans mentions, there are performance implications of switching between MSIL and machine code generation for a particular function.  But if you are sitting on a native-managed boundary, then compilation to MSIL and use of the "It Just Works" a/k/a "C++ interop" is by far the highest performance alternative.